# about gatsby link issue

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, contentful

I created my own blog with gatsby and contentful using template. And I was tring to change subdirctory of my arcticels. article URLs are working now but links in index page is not working.

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'gatsby'
import { GatsbyImage } from 'gatsby-plugin-image'

import Container from './container'
import Tags from './tags'
import * as styles from './article-preview.module.css'

const ArticlePreview = ({ posts }) => {
  if (!posts) return null
  if (!Array.isArray(posts)) return null

  return (
    <Container>
      <ul className={styles.articleList}>
        {posts.map((post) => {
          return (
            <li key={post.slug}>
              <Link to={`/${post.category}/${post.slug}`} className={styles.link}>
                <GatsbyImage alt="" image={post.heroImage.gatsbyImageData} />
                <h2 className={styles.title}>{post.title}</h2>
              </Link>
              <div
                dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                  __html: post.description.childMarkdownRemark.html,
                }}
              />
              <div className={styles.meta}>
                <small className="meta">{post.publishDate}</small>
                <Tags tags={post.tags} />
              </div>
            </li>
          )
        })}
      </ul>
    </Container>
  )
}

export default ArticlePreview
```

I changed to `<Link to={`/${post.category}/${post.slug}`}` from <Link to={`/${post.slug}`}. but somehow links are like http://localhost:8000/undefined/(article-slug). It shold be category name as I set up in Comtentful insted of 'undefined'.

do you have any suggestions?

if I use subdir like /blog/, its working. and Link to={`/${post.slug}/${post.slug}`} also work.

Comment: console log the `posts` json

Comment: I rebuild and got these error ` ERROR #95313 

Building static HTML failed

See our docs page for more info on this error: https://gatsby.dev/debug-html

  Error: Error loading a result for the page query in "/diary/newyear2023/". Query was not run and no cached result was found.

Comment: does your subpages exist, are you generate them from gatsby node api createPages?

Comment: Unless you share you page creation (`gatsby-node.js`) for those posts and you template query it's impossible to know why it's undefined.